# Cisco Catalyst 3750 disable Factory default reset with Button press

Tags: networking, cisco, switch

The Catalyst 3750 Series switch  has a front panel button which erases the config and reboots the switch if pressed more than 10 seconds.

In a dense Rack it happened more than once to me that cables pressed the button and therefore resetted the switch to factory default.

Searching through the cisco docs and asking aunt google I haven't found a way to disable this behavior, does someone here know how to disable this?

Comment: If you don't find anything to turn this off, just tape some small screw nut or similar shaped item around it so the cables can't touch the actual reset switch anymore. Yes, it's a hack but it's simple and effective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`no setup express`](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2950/software/release/12-1_19_ea1/command/reference/2950cr/cli2.html#wp3550000) command disables the functionality that resets the configuration when the MODE button is held. I suspect this will do what you're looking for.